# FullCalendar scheduler update resource JSON object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm working with Rails and FullCalendar Scheduler and I want to be able to update the JSON object I give as resource when I add a new one.

Here is a simplified version of my calendar options:

**fullcalendar-settings.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'promptResource, prev, next, today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek, timelineDay'
        },
        customButtons: {
          promptResource: {
              text: '+ maker',
              click: function() {
                  var name = prompt('Name');
                  if (name) {
                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                          'addResource', { title: name }, true // scroll to the new source?
                      );
                  }
              }
          }
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        defaultDate: moment(),
        editable: true,
        resourceColumns: [
            {
                labelText: 'Client',
                field: 'title'
            }
        ],
        resources: 'scheduler.json',
        events: []
    });
});
```

**scheduler.json**

```
[
  { "id": "1", "title": "LE" },
  { "id": "2", "title": "DB" },
  { "id": "3", "title": "VB" },
  { "id": "7", "title": "RL" }
]
```

Resources are loaded from 'scheduler.json' and I have a button with which you can add a new resource but it is for now only temporary and disappear on reload.

So my question is how can I update the JSON object within 'scheduler.json' when I add a new resource ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to send an ajax request after you create an event in the calendar to update your db which will generate the scheduler.json file next time you reload the page.

Comment: I'm ok with the JSON but not sure how to do this kind of request though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn Jquery Ajax. And you need to read the documentation of FullCalendar. There is no other way. But, if you need a quick fix you can [watch this screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiTLuPqvt58). This will meet your requirement for sure I am guessing.